# SQL Developer - 11g Database - Debug Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an issue with Oracle SQL Developer, when I try to debug an Procedure that i compiled for debugging, i get the folling error:

[image]

The code for my procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE kmpr_valida_saldo_ebs (
    in_cd_material        IN    VARCHAR2,
    in_ebs_quantidade     IN    VARCHAR2,
    out_resp              OUT   VARCHAR2
) IS
    v_quantidade NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
    -- Realiza a consulta no Oracle EBS.

    SELECT
        moq.transaction_quantity - in_ebs_quantidade
    INTO
        v_quantidade        
    FROM
        apps.mtl_onhand_quantities@k2prd        moq
        LEFT JOIN apps.mtl_system_items_b@k2prd msib
        ON moq.inventory_item_id = msib.inventory_item_id
    WHERE
        moq.subinventory_code = 'KMB_GER'  --Filtro do depósito de Barueri
        AND msib.segment1 = in_cd_material --Filtro da peça sendo consultada
        AND moq.organization_id = 151      --Filtro da organização 151 de Barueri
    GROUP BY
        moq.transaction_quantity;

    -- Verifica se a quantidade é maior que 0, retorna OK se for, retorna erro SE0005 caso não seja.
    IF ( v_quantidade >= 0 ) THEN
        out_resp := 'OK';
    ELSE
        SELECT
            'Código '
            || code
            || ' - '
            || description
        INTO out_resp
        FROM
            kmtb_message
        WHERE
            code = 'SE0005';

        return;
    END IF;

END;
```

But I think the issue is not at the procedure because any procedure won't work when I try to debug.

Someone knows what can i do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That error is not caused by this code.  There is no table alias `A` or column reference `DEFAULTED`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the log was clean when i tried to test the procedure.

Comment: @victorarakaki The code you are showing does not include the column with the error. Maybe the query references views that in turn access a function/procedure that uses it? Anyway, there's not enough info in the question. Voting to close.